# The resource identifier failed to decrypt

Tags: iis-8

We are hosting a site that has sitefinity, the site is crashing frequently and getting the error given below:

============================

Event code: 3012

Event message: An error occurred processing a web or script resource request. The resource identifier failed to decrypt. 
Event time: 8/4/2016 1:09:19 PM 
Event time (UTC): 8/4/2016 6:09:19 PM 
Event ID: 9ed7856e9baa479f944599104bda8f46 
Event sequence: 1265 
Event occurrence: 6 
Event detail code: 0

Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Unable to validate data.
at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData)
at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s, Purpose purpose)
at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

Stack trace: at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData)
at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s, Purpose purpose)
at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

+++++++++++++++++

I have already implemented the steps given in the URL:

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/event-code-3012

Please let me know if you need any additional logs

Please advice.

Regards,

Comment: I doubt the site crashes because of this error. I've seen it on numerous occasions and it was never the root cause of a site crash. Look for something else in the Sitefinity logs / windows event viewer

Answer (score 1):

Set machine decryption key same at all application servers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx